# Issue Importing Template to Overleaf

Tags: templates

I'm somewhat new to Latex and trying to use overleaf with a template I imported. However, I get the following error right at the beginning after `\documentclass[12pt,chapterheads]{ucsd}` is called.

```
Runaway definition?
->\let @mkboth \markboth \def @oddfoot {\hbox {}\hfil \rmfamily \thepage \ETC
.
File ended while scanning definition of \ps@plain.

}
l.94
```

No idea what it means. Can anyone help me out? I'm willing to answer any other questions needed to specify my problem.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! `uscd.cls` is not an official documentclass and it has an error (a missing `}`) in its definition of the "thesis" page style.  I suggest you use a standard latex documentclass, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/782/15925

Comment: Ah so the missing bracket is in the class file, not the template?

Comment: Yes, it is the class file that is at fault.

Comment: Thank you by the way. I want to use this class because its specifically made for the university's guidelines, so I'm going to try to find where the error is. I'm struggling though because \let "@mkboth \markboth \def @oddfoot"

Does not appear in the class file.

Comment: The class is on git-hub at https://github.com/ucsd-thesis/ucsd-thesis, there it specifically says it is not an official style.

Answer (score 1):

The error is from the documentclass file `uscd.cls`.  This is an unofficial document class available from git-hub at https://github.com/ucsd-thesis/ucsd-thesis.  The error in the class file is a missing closing bracket `}` on line 1585.  The definition the "thesis" page style should read:

```
% Definition of 'thesis' page style.
%
\def\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\markboth%
\def\@oddfoot{\hbox{}\hfil\rmfamily\thepage\hfil\hbox{}}% Pgno bot center
\def\@evenfoot{\hbox{}\hfil\rmfamily\thepage\hfil\hbox{}}%
\def\@oddhead{}% heading (right)
\def\@evenhead{}% heading (left)
%\pagenumbering{arabic}}                    % (WBB)
}
```

note the final line.  You should report this to the maintainer of the class.

I don't know the mechanisms of overleaf, you might be able to upload your own private copy of the file and make the change there.