# Where do I find refined classes?

Tags: document-classes

I'm somewhat new to TeX I have made a few documents using the article class in LaTeX but I don't have any other experience. I was reading through the TeX FAQ when I found this entry: http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-clsvpkg. [image: Extract from the entry]

When I searched in CTAN I didn't get any results for refined classes.
Where exactly am I supposed to look for refined classes?

Comment: It is more or less something like KOMA, memoir and tufte, classes with different default layout, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: This question seems to be a good address for an extensive overview: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/782/220875 and this of course for inspiration: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/220875

Comment: @phil-elkabat and TeXnician Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no statistical evidence for "aren't widely liked."  I suspect most document classes are the result of one person (each) with OCD and their own brand of aesthetics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my own answer from here: [What are the available "documentclass" types and their uses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/782/220875).

I've decided to use the KOMA script bundle