# Why does Overleaf not compile the current file?

Tags: compiling, overleaf

In some of my projects, Overleaf would not compile the current file I had open (but rather the original file that was open), while in other projects it would always compile the current file. Any idea why this might occur?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that the issue was that I did not have the `\documentclass` command written at the top of the file (I had instead written this in a separate `preamble.tex` file and done `\input{preamble}`). If there is no `\documentclass` command in the file, then Overleaf will not compile it when you switch to that file!

Comment: How many document classes are there? The only one I have encountered is `article`.

Comment: @A-levelStudent Maybe take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/782/what-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses.