# what is the difference between Article and Report documentclass

Tags: document-classes

** Please explain the difference between article and report documentclass in LaTex**
This question was asked in my exam for 10 marks so I want to know answer

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/789/87678

Comment: I didn't get clarity

Comment: Hello please answer my question