# How I can write on Overleaf, which the abstract on no columns and the other sections on two columns?

Tags: two-column, article, abstract

How I can write on Overleaf, which the abstract on no columns  and the other sections on two columns? (exactly as the picture)[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where do you have the picture/pdf from? Have you asked for the used class there?

Comment: Like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121705/11604).

Comment: Yes, thanks so much