# How to crop my page to the size of tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, crop

I want to crop the page to exactly fit the tikz graph in it. When i used `standalone` document class, all the page content became on one line. Here is my code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzstyle{myarrow}=[draw=black,-triangle 45]
\begin{document}
$X^2$ = $\frac{c}{b}$ \\

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [myarrow] (0,0) -- (13,0) node [at end, below] {$\lambda$};
    \draw (0,2.2) -- (12,2.2);
    \draw[ultra thick, black] (0,0) sin (3,2);
    \draw[ultra thick, red] (3,2) cos (6,0);
    \draw[ultra thick, black] (6,0) sin (9,-2);
    \draw[ultra thick, red] (9,-2) cos (12,0);
\end{tikzpicture}\\

$A$  \hspace{1cm}Hello \\

C               \hspace{1.3cm}hello  \\

B        \hspace{1cm}hello \\

d               \hspace{1.4cm}hello  \\
\end{document}
```

**I want the result to be like this**
[image]

**But here is what i got**
[image]

I also tried `preview` but it didn't work
[Got the ideas from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-can-i-create-a-pdf-document-exactly-as-big-as-my-tikz-picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `varwidth` option for standalone to enclose the contents in a `varwidth` environment (from the `varwidth` package). I had to specify some width for the option to avoid the `\lambda` and the arrow on the left from being cropped out:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=80cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzstyle{myarrow}=[draw=black,-triangle 45]

\begin{document}

$X^2$ = $\frac{c}{b}$ \par
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [myarrow] (0,0) -- (13,0) node [at end, below] {$\lambda$};
    \draw (0,2.2) -- (12,2.2);
    \draw[ultra thick, black] (0,0) sin (3,2);
    \draw[ultra thick, red] (3,2) cos (6,0);
    \draw[ultra thick, black] (6,0) sin (9,-2);
    \draw[ultra thick, red] (9,-2) cos (12,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

$A$  \hspace{1cm}Hello\par\bigskip

C               \hspace{1.3cm}hello\par\bigskip

B        \hspace{1cm}hello\par\bigskip

d               \hspace{1.4cm}hello

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use the `border` option to add some border, if required.

Not related to the question, but please never use  `\\` followed by `\par` (or a blank line); you can use `\par\bigskip` instead, if need be. I don't quite understand why you have all those `\hspace`s in your code. Perhaps you are trying to achieve an enumerated list? In this case, use the `enumerate` environment.

Comment: Why not using the `varwidth` option to `standalone`?

Comment: @egreg Yes, why not? :-) I wasn't aware of the class already offering this feature. Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I'm trying to make equal spaces between the two columns, so i used `\hspace`. Do you have any other ideas to do that?.