# Generate pdf document consisting in just one figure

Tags: standalone, chemfig

Related to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-can-i-create-a-pdf-document-exactly-as-big-as-my-tikz-picture) I am trying to generate a figure using package chemfig.
Actually, my problem is that the lower part of the figure is cropped, specifically the H under the N.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-\chembelow{\color{blue}N}{H}-(={\color{red}O})-{\color{blue}N}=(-{\color{blue}N}H_2)-=)}
\end{document}
```

Below, you see the figure as I got:

[image]

and as it should be:

[image]

Comment: Is there an environment version of `\chemfig`? e.g. `\begin{chemfig}... \end{chemfig}`? If so, use that and add `\standaloneenv{chemfig}` to the preamble.

Comment: @cfr I'm curious: why would or should that help?

Comment: @clements In fact, it does not help.

Comment: @clemens It might not but it does with e.g. `forest`. If you are using `forest`, setting `\standaloneenv{forest` helps `standalone` get the cropping etc. correct. Especially if you are using `multi` because `standalone` starts a new page for each `standaloneenv`, which does not include `forest` by default. But I don't know if there is a macro equivalent e.g. `\standalonecmd{}` - I've never seen this. Then again, maybe I've just not looked in the right place?

Comment: @cfr Ah OK. I never used `forest` so I can't compare if the problems are anywhere similar to `\chembelow` in this case…

Comment: @clemens And I've never used `\chembelow` so I can't either ;). This is why it was a comment rather than an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\Chembelow` (upper case!) instead of `\chembelow`. From the manual (emphasis by me):

> The macro[...]
>
> ```
> \chembelow[<dim>]{<code>}{<stuff>}
> ```
>
> place[s] the `<stuff>` [...] below the `<code>` [...] *without
>   changing the bounding box of `<code>`*.

The uppercase version on the other hand `does` extend the bounding box. (`\lewis` and `\Lewis` have the same relationship, by the way.)

Comment: It works! Great!

Answer (score 1):

The `Chembelow` macro can be used but the result is *not* perfect since the bounding box (too high) modifies the position of bonds coming and leaving `N`:

[image]

`\Chembelow` cannot give a good result and `\chembelow` sends `H` outside the croping. A solution is to use an invisible bond (the `.25` lenght found with try/error):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-\color{blue}{N}(-[,.25,,,draw=none]H)-(={\color{red}O})-{\color{blue}N}=(-{\color{blue}N}H_2)-=)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Pershaps the better solution, but more verbose, is to use `\chemfig*` (with a star) since it the length of the invisible bond can be set to 0 (0 is 0.0001 for tikz):

```
\chemfig*{*6(-\color{blue}{N}(-[,.0001,,,draw=none]{\lower0.25ex\hbox{H}})-(={\color{red}O})-{\color{blue}N}=(-{\color{blue}N}H_2)-=)}
```