# Trimming the blank space in PDF image for insertion in TeX file

Tags: graphics, pdf, wide-image

I have an image in PDF format like this:

[image]

There's a lot of empty space in the bottom half of the image. When I insert the PDF image in `main.tex` using `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4x4_System_Circuit.pdf}` the blank space of the image also gets included. Can that blank space somehow be trimmed out? Otherwise, it looks weird.

P.S: You can see the code I used to generate the PDF image [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/read/cwztnthrscyt).

Comment: (because in OP's case the graphics is generated from TeX code that the author can control, [paper size - How can I create a pdf document exactly as big as my tikz picture? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-can-i-create-a-pdf-document-exactly-as-big-as-my-tikz-picture?noredirect=1&lq=1) also applies)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim = 1cm 2cm 0cm 1cm, clip]{test-image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where `trim=left bottom right top` specifies by how much the image/pdf gets clipped.

### Find trim parameters

To find the trim parameters, you can draw an `fbox` around your image and see the area that will be clipped (marked by a black rectangle). Once you found the correct area, delete the `fbox` and add the `clip` key.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim = 1cm 2cm 0cm 1cm]{test-image}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Alternative: Use `standalone` document class for your input pdf

As you are producing the input pdf as well, you can set the document class for this pdf (4x4_System_Circuit.pdf) to `standalone`. This will automatically produce a pdf that has the right size. No clipping will be needed. For information on how to use the `standalone` class, see the [standalone class manual](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf), section 5.

Answer (score 12):

Most latex installations come with the `pdfcrop` command line tool.

Simply run

```
pdfcrop filename.pdf
```

This creates a new pdf (`filename-crop.pdf`) where the excessive whitespace have been removed. And the just include this new file.

As the name suggests, this only work on pdf files.